# JavaScript Code Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

My java script code is not working, Currently when you select a value in the first drop down menu the second drop down menu becomes editable which is fine. But I want to make it as if when you select the option 'default' in the first drop down menu the second drop down menu reverts to 'default' and becomes disabled and read only, but if I select any other option other then 'default' the second menu should be editable.

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function mySecondFunction() {
 var ddl = document.getElementById("1");
 var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
    if (selectedValue == "Default")
   {
    document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = true;
   }else {
    document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = false;
   }

}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<select  id="1" onchange="mySecondFunction()">
                <option value="OptionZero">Default</option>
                <option value="OptionOne">Car</option>
                <option value="OptionTwo">Car2</option>
                <option value="OptionThree">Car23</option>
</select>
<br>
<select disabled id="mySelection">
                <option value="OptionZero">Default</option>
                <option value="OptionOne">A</option>
                <option value="OptionTwo">B</option>
                <option value="OptionThree">C</option>
        </select>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The value is not "Default", it's "OptionZero"

Answer (score 1):

You should write

```
if(selectedValue == "OptionZero") {
```

It is the value attribute which set the value on an element.

Answer (score 0):

Try as

```
function mySecondFunction() {
  var ddl = document.getElementById("1");
  var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
  if (selectedValue == "OptionZero")
    {
     document.getElementById('mySelection').selectedIndex = 0;
      document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = true;
   }else {
    document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = false;
   }

}
```

OR CAN WE TRY AS

```
function mySecondFunction() {
 var ddl = document.getElementById("1");
 var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;
    if (selectedValue == "Default")
   {
    document.getElementById('mySelection').selectedIndex = 0;
    document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = true;
   }else {
    document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = false;
   }

}
```

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/5n7L91e8/1/)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5n7L91e8/)

[**UPDATE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5n7L91e8/2/)

Comment: How do I make the second drop down go back to default when its disabled? So If I enable the second drop down and select optionOne = A but then I select default in the first drop down, how do I make the second drop down go back to default and make it read only

Answer (score 0):

You need to use value `OptionZero` and not the Label `Default`, and set the value back in "mySelection"

```
if (selectedValue == "OptionZero")
{
    document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = true;
    // set the value to default
    document.getElementById("mySelection").value = "OptionZero"
} else {
    document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake with the value, this is the answer:

```
function mySecondFunction() {
  var ddl = document.getElementById("1");
  var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = selectedValue === "OptionZero"?true:false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Script like this

```
function mySecondFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById("1").value == "OptionZero")
   {
    document.getElementById("mySelection").value="OptionZero";
    document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = true;
   }else {       
    document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = false;
   }
}
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmn2pvcu/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the following code.

```
   <html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function mySecondFunction() {
  var ddl = document.getElementById("1");
  var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
 if (selectedValue == "OptionZero")
  {
  document.getElementById("mySelection").value="OptionZero";
  document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = true;
  }else {
  document.getElementById("mySelection").disabled = false;
  }

 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select  id="1" onchange="mySecondFunction()">
            <option value="OptionZero">Default</option>
            <option value="OptionOne">Car</option>
            <option value="OptionTwo">Car2</option>
            <option value="OptionThree">Car23</option>
</select><br>
 <select disabled id="mySelection">
            <option value="OptionZero">Default</option>
            <option value="OptionOne">A</option>
            <option value="OptionTwo">B</option>
            <option value="OptionThree">C</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Please change 
        selectedValue == "Default" 
to 
        selectedValue == "OptionZero" 
and add the following line in if condition
    document.getElementById("mySelection").value="OptionZero";

Hope it will help you.Thank you.